# How to replace session attribute

Tags: java, session, weblogic

I am sharing a session under ear. It has two wars, but I am getting an error while trying set a attribute which is already present in the session.I am not able to override it.

Below are my code first three are working but at 4th line programe crashes. It is working in dev.

```
   logger.info("before test");
    session.setAttribute("test","testInsert");
    logger.info("afterTEST"+session);//weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SharedSessionData@
    session.setAttribute("test","testInsert");
    logger.info("before saving");
```

Comment: Does it give an error message of some kind? Are you using the sessionScope variable when you first share it?

Comment: Can you please share the exception/error you are getting ?

Comment: its just giving Xyz(Servlet) class - null